# Binary Search Tree Height function help (python)

Tags: python, function, binary-search-tree

Learning binary search trees and came across a function, I was able to get it working but don't understand why.

```
    def height(self):
        """
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Returns the maximum height of a BST, i.e. the length of the
        largest path from root to a leaf node in the tree.
        Use: h = bst.height()
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Returns:
            maximum height of bst (int)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        
        if self._root is not None:
            height = self._height(self._root)
        else:
            height = 0
            
        return height
    
    def _height(self, node):
        
        if node is None:
            height = 0
        else:
            left_height = self._height(node._left)
            right_height = self._height(node._right)
            height = max(left_height, right_height) + 1
        return height
```

This code is the one that works, the only difference is line right above the return height where it's +1. The line used to be

```
height = max(left_height, right_height)
```

The old line always just returned 0, anybody want to explain how adding the 1 got it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add 1 because it's the level you are on plus the max height of the 2 subtrees:

```
height = max(left_height, right_height) + 1
```